# Make identical objects move independently in Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

So I am trying to make a simple space game. You will have a ship that moves left and right, and Asteroids will be generated above the top of the canvas at random X position and size and they will move down towards the ship.

How can I create Asteroid objects in seperate positions? Like having more than one existing in the canvas at once, without creating them as totally seperate objects with seperate variables?

This sets the variables I would like the asteroid to be created on.

```
 var asteroids = {
size: Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 15),
startY: 100,
startX: Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width-200) + 200),
speed: 1
}
```

This is what I used to draw the asteroid. (It makes a hexagon shape with random size at a random x coordinate)

```
function drawasteroid() {
this.x = asteroids.startX;
this.y = 100;
this.size = asteroids.size;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y-this.size*0.5);
ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.size*0.9,this.y);
ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.size*0.9,this.y+this.size*1);
ctx.lineTo(this.x,this.y+this.size*1.5);
ctx.lineTo(this.x-this.size*0.9,this.y+this.size*1);
ctx.lineTo(this.x-this.size*0.9,this.y);
ctx.fill();
```

}

I included ALL of my code in this snippet. Upon running it, you will see that I currently have a ship that moves and the asteroid is drawn at a random size and random x coordinate. I just need to know about how to go about making the asteroid move down while creating other new asteroids that will also move down.

Thank You for all your help! I am new to javascript.

```js
// JavaScript Document

////// Variables //////
var canvas = {width:300, height:500, fps:30};
var score = 0;

var player = {
 x:canvas.width/2,
 y:canvas.height-100,
 defaultSpeed: 5,
 speed: 10
 };
 
var asteroids = {
 size: Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 15),
 startY: 100,
 startX: Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width-200) + 200),
 speed: 1
}

var left = false;
var right = false;



////// Arrow keys //////

function onkeydown(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 37) { 
   left = true;
  } 
  
  if(e.keyCode === 39) {
   right = true; 
  } 
}

function onkeyup(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) { 
   left = false;
  } 
  
  if(e.keyCode === 39) {
   right = false; 
  } 
}
 

////// other functions //////


//function to clear canvas
function clearCanvas() {
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

// draw the score in the upper left corner
function drawscore(score) {
 var score = 0;
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
 ctx.fillText(score,50,50);
}

// Draw Player ship.
function ship(x,y) {
 var x = player.x;
 var y = player.y;
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";

 ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+15,y+50);
    ctx.lineTo(x-15,y+50);
    ctx.fill();
}

// move player ship.
function moveShip() {
 document.onkeydown = onkeydown;
 document.onkeyup = onkeyup;
 if (left === true && player.x > 50) {
  player.x -= player.speed;
 }
 if (right === true && player.x < canvas.width - 50) {
  player.x += player.speed;
 }
}


// Draw Asteroid
function drawasteroid() {
 this.x = asteroids.startX;
 this.y = 100;
 this.size = asteroids.size;
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
 
 ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y-this.size*0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.size*0.9,this.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.size*0.9,this.y+this.size*1);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x,this.y+this.size*1.5);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x-this.size*0.9,this.y+this.size*1);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x-this.size*0.9,this.y);
    ctx.fill();
  
}

// move Asteroid
function moveAsteroid() {
 //don't know how I should go about this.
}



// update
setInterval (update, 1000/canvas.fps);

function update() {
 
// test collisions and key inputs
 moveShip();
 
// redraw the next frame of the animation
 clearCanvas();
 drawasteroid();
 drawscore();
 ship();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Game</title>   

<script src="game-functions.js"></script>

<!--
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
-->
        
</head>

<body>

<canvas id="ctx" width="300" height="500" style="border: thin solid black; background-color: black;"></canvas>
<br>


<script>
////// Canvas setup //////
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to make them separate objects that you put in an array? That way you can iterate over your array of asteroids and move each one with every setainterval call. You can make a condition to remove an asteroid from the array once it is off the canvas. You can also specify a max of asteroids by adding an additional one only if the array is a certain length.

Comment: Is that a proper way to do it though?

I figure that will end up with a lot of identical code with variables under different names. (asteroid1, asteroid2, asteroid3, asteroid4, asteroid5)

Comment: Is there a way of doing such a thing where the variable name itself would change for seperate asteroids? if is was asteroid# and the # would be replaced with a new number for each new asteroid?  I know it wouldnt be #, but you get what I mean?

Comment: Do the edits to my answer address your question?

Comment: Yes. I mean, I'm a beginner, so I don't fully understand how to use arrays properly.  But I'm heading in the right direction now. Thank you!

Comment: Ah well that could make my explanation a little more difficult to understand as I didn't know you were a novice programmer, assumed just beginner at javascript. Let me know if you have trouble implementing it. I would also recommend a tutorial on basic javascript stuff like objects, arrays and how the setInterval function gets managed by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the creation of asteroids dynamic...so why not set up a setInterval that gets called at random intervals as below. You don't need a separate declaration for each Asteroids object you create. You can just declare a temporary one in a setInterval function. This will instantiate multiple different objects with the same declaration. Of course you need to store each object somewhere which is precisely what the array is for.

You also have to make sure that asteroids get removed from the array whenever the moveAsteroid function is called if they are off of the canvas. The setInterval function below should be called on window load and exists alongside your main rendering setInterval function.

You are also going to have to change your moveAsteroid function a bit to be able to point to a specific Asteroids object from the array. You can do this by adding the Asteroids object as a parameter of the function or by making the function a property of the Asteroids class and using *this*. I did the latter in the example below.

```
 var astArray = [];
 var manageAsteroidFrequency = 2000;


 var Asteroids {
      X: //something
      Y://something
      speed:1
      move: function() {
             this.X -= speed;
       }

   }


 var mainRenderingFunction = setInterval( function() {

      for (var i = astArray.length-1 ; i > -1; i --){
            if(astArray[i].Y < 0){
                 astArray.splice(i, 1)
             }else{
                 astArray[i].move;
              }
        }

  }, 40);


 var manageAsteroids = setInterval( function () {

       if (astArray.length < 4){
             var tmpAst = new Asteroids();
             astArray.push(tmpAst);
           }

       manageAsteroidFrequency = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
       }, manageAsteroidFrequency);
```